# Unable to access Docker Daemon from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running Jenkins inside a docker container.

I use the following command to start the container -

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v "${PWD}:/var/jenkins_home" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock aemdesign/jenkins
```

Notice `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` - I have done this so that I can access the docker daemon from within Jenkins as per [this](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) article.

I `cd` into the jenkins container using `docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash`

I then run `docker ps -a` but I still get docker command not found error.

I did some more research online and found out about the docker plugin for Jenkins, and configured it to connect to the docker daemon. I get the following error

[image]

Am I missing something? How do I solve this issue? Please note that I am doing this locally on a MAC machine.

Comment: Try adding the `jenkins` user to the `docker` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, this just means your container has ability to access `docker daemon` on the host, not mean your container will have the `docker client`.

You could use `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` to add `docker client` to your container, then you will find the command.

```
 docker run -u root -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v "${PWD}:/var/jenkins_home" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock aemdesign/jenkins
```

Another way if you want reserve jenkins user.

```
docker run -u jenkins:$(cut -d: -f3 < <(getent group docker)) -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v "${PWD}:/var/jenkins_home" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock aemdesign/jenkins
```

Comment: I ran the command as suggested by you. I am able to run docker commands from within Jenkins container but only when I am the root user - "docker exec -it -u root <mycontainer> /bin/bash", otherwise I get a permission denied error. Basically I want to run docker commands from within jenkins pipelines.

Comment: Update, you can either use `-u root` to start jenkins container, or use `-u jenkins:gid` to reserve jenkins user.